# Error while working with mqtt broker in angular

Tags: angular, mqtt

I have created a new angular app and wanted to use it with mqtt broker. I am following this tutorial - http://www.davidfindlay.com.au/monitoring-mqtt-services-in-an-angular-web-application/.

I have installed ng2-mqtt through angular cli.

I have imported

```
import {Paho} from 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31';
```

in my component.ts

when i do ng serve it compiles sucessfully, but browser throws an error

```
mqttws31.js:84 Uncaught ReferenceError: Paho is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/ng2-mqtt/mqttws31.js (mqttws31.js:84)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/ahu/ahu.component.ts (main.js:104)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Any idea what is causing the error.

Comment: Which Angular version are you working with?

Comment: Hi @HardikShah , I am using angular 8

Comment: Use this one. https://sclausen.github.io/ngx-mqtt/

Comment: @cvg have you found a solutions ? i've the same error only when i run "ng build --prod"

Comment: Hi, couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem. Solved it by following the instruction in https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/76

simply navigate to ng2-mqtt in node_modules and replace

```
if (typeof Paho === "undefined") {
Paho = {};
}
```

with

```
const Paho = {};
```

in mqttws31.js